# Why can I not access a textbox.text property on my webform?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a master page with a TextBox and LinkButton. If I enter text in the TextBox and try to access it from the click event of the LinkButton it is always returned as an empty string. I am trying to pick up the entered text and pass it as a parameter to another page.

Example code:

```
Response.Redirect(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(String.Concat("~/Pages/SearchResults.aspx?search=", Me.SearchTextBox.Text.Trim)))
```

Comment: Are the textbox and the link button both on the masterpage? Does the page you are on at the time set the textbox to blank in page_load or init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim searchbox as TextBox = TryCast(Me.MasterPage.FindControl("SearchTextBox"), TextBox)

If searchBox IsNot Nothing
    Response.Redirect(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(String.Concat("~/Pages/SearchResults.aspx?search=", searchbox .Text.Trim)))
End If
```

Comment: Perfect! This fixed it for me (removed the 'MasterPage' bit as both controls are on the master). Any idea what was going wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 1):

I would expose the controls as public properties on the Master page.  This will give you better design-time support.

**Master Page**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" />

  public string Firstname 
    {
        get { return txtFirstName.Text; }       
    }
```

**Child Page**

```
<asp:Literal ID="litText" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnMasterText" Text="Submit" runat="server" 
onclick="btnMasterText_Click" />

   protected void btnMasterText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myMasterPage = Page.Master as SiteMaster;
        litText.Text = myMasterPage.Firstname;
    }
```

"SiteMaster" is the name of the Master page in the project.